# Removing duplicated values from row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this (just some fakedata to show example):

[image: example]

Problem is here is the duplicate accountnames in column account_name

I need help to understand how I can remove the duplicates or by either some sort of alter table or a select so lets say account1 only shows once, account 2 and so on under site1

The real table contains a lot more columns, been trying working around this with distincts and groups by but not had any progress.

Any pointing in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 22621: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: What do you want your final result to look like? Are you asking how you can manipulate `account_name` to be a comma delimited list of _unique_ names? Or do you want your result as a table, with one row for each `url` and distinct `account_name`?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear, been working for 16h.

@xendi The wish is to have the table like the picture above but to have comma delimited list of uniqe account_names, with no duplicates that is.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Well hopefully that shows why not to store data in comma delimited format. So you will have to convert it to a real table of data, from which you can detect and remove duplicated and then convert it back to a comma delimited format. All of these steps have been solved many many times before and solutions easily found.

Comment: Side question: why have you not installed any updates on your instance in the last 4-5 years? The RTM version 2019 has multiple (fixed) bugs, and (addressed) security issues

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is avoid storing delimited strings in the first place. However we don't always get what we want. So here's what I would do.

First, `string_split` the results to get a row for each account name. then `group by url, account_name` to get the distinct rows. Finally, reconstruct your delimited string using `string_agg`.

Note, I'm using `trim` to clean up whitespace. If you don't want to do that, I guess you could skip that step.

```
;with a (url, account_name) as
(
    select 'z', 'a,a,a,b,c' union all
    select 'y', 'a,b,b,b,c'
),b as
(

    select Url, value = trim(value)
    from a
    cross apply string_split(account_name, ',') b
    group by url, trim(value)
)
select url, account_name = string_agg(value, ',')
from b
group by url
```

| url | account_name |
| --- | --- |
| y | a,b,c |
| z | a,b,c |

Comment: Why reanswer when there is a clear duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, STRING_AGG(account_name, ', ') AS concatenated_accounts
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT url, TRIM(account_name.value) as account_name
    FROM (
        SELECT 'https://site1' AS url, 'Domain\account1, Domain\account1, Domain\account1, Domain\account1, Domain\account2, Domain\account1' AS account_name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'https://sites2' AS url, 'Domain\account1, Domain\account1, Domain\account2, Domain\account2, Domain\account3' AS account_name) AS DataSet
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(account_name, ',') AS account_name) AS CrossApplyDataSet
GROUP BY URL
```

[image]

| url | concatenated_accounts |
| --- | --- |
| https://site1 | Domain\account1, Domain\account2 |
| https://sites2 | Domain\account1, Domain\account2, Domain\account3 |

You now just need to do the work to get it back into your table.

Comment: Why include an image as well as the text version? As I am sure you are aware, images are discouraged for anything but UI related questions.

Comment: @DaleK I am sorry, was so insanely tired yesterday I should not have posted at all. Was in pure desperation to get this sorted out by any means. 

Rereading the question I'm not sure what I was thinking..